# How do I allow a single Wordpress site to accept my .ttf file upload?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, fonts, web-development-server

I'm using the Font Organizer plugin for Wordpress. It has a nice option to upload a font, which I have saved to my computer. I just need to somehow get Wordpress to accept it so I can use it here:

[image]

However, I'm getting an error: `Error uploading the file: Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.`

How do I let Wordpress temporarily allow this? Also, is this method even going to work out? The end goal is for it to show up on the drop down list in the image above because I need to change the font of the header text. I can do any programming stuff needed.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately for me neither the code snippet for **functions.php** or the plugin worked.

I had to temporarily add the following code to **wp-config.php**:

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

And then of course deleted it as soon as I had uploaded the font.

(However in future I will attempt to use compressed font versions as suggested in the bottom two answers).

Answer (score 7):

You can allow uploading the .ttf font on your site, by adding a simple filter code on function.php file.

Below is the code for .ttf font only

```
    add_filter('upload_mimes', 'add_custom_upload_mimes');
    function add_custom_upload_mimes($existing_mimes) {
        $existing_mimes['ttf'] = 'application/x-font-ttf';
        return $existing_mimes;
   }
```

You can add more MIME type in the function to allow to upload those file.

Comment: This does not work for me. I can allow another file types this way (svg, otf), but ttf - application/x-font-ttf is ignored by wordpress. Don't you know why?

Comment: For anyone else this didn't work for see this post to force MIME type detection for TTF file extension: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/396325/how-can-i-allow-upload-of-ttf-or-otf-font-files-when-hooking-upload-mimes-does/396326#396326

Answer (score 3):

There is [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-mime-types/) that allow you to whitelist certain mime types.

Also the `add_filter` hook can be used to extend the default allowed mime types from a theme or plugin.

*P.S.: You really shouldn't use ttf for web use, since it's uncompressed. Use woff, woff2 or eot instead.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use a code snippet to add support for certain mime types, or use a plugin to enable that feature. Or you could avoid the issue at all by converting the file to a compressed version, for example using an online converter like https://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-woff

This was the first one I run into while trying to solve your very same problem; it's not the best or the fastest or anything: it just works.

Comment: And..why the downvote? What's wrong, what could be enhanced?

Comment: Certainly got my upvote, great tip re the online converter!

Comment: In my WordPress, woff font's are not allowed to ...

Comment: Yes @MarcoFloriano you usually can upload a woff font via a Theme or a plugin that allows it for theming purposes. Wordpress on its own does not allow it :-)